# How can i find the total number of elements in a form?

Tags: javascript

I try to store the length of a form on a variable but it doesnt work.This is my first attempt with javascript.

```
var lista = new Array();

var numOfEl = document.psonia.elements.length;
function ektipwsi() {
    for(var i=0; i < numOfEl ; i++){
        if(document.psonia.elements[i].checked) {
            lista.push(document.psonia.elements[i].value);
        }
    };
```

I also tried with getElementById or getElementByTag with no luck.
This is the entire form i use

```
<div>
<form name="psonia">
    <div class = "laxanika">
        <h2 class="epik">Λαχανικά</h2>
            <div class="transp">
                <input type="checkbox" value="Ντομάτες">Ντομάτες<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Πατάτες">Πατάτες<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Αγγούρια">Αγγούρια<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Μελιτζάνες">Μελιτζάνες<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Κρεμμύδια">Κρεμμύδια<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Κρεμ.Στιφ.">Κρεμ.Στιφ.<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Μαρούλι">Μαρούλι<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Λάχανο">Λάχανο<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Πιπεριές">Πιπεριές<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Φλωρίνης">Φλωρίνης<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Σκόρδα">Σκόρδα<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Ρόκα">Ρόκα<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Κολοκύθια">Κολοκύθια<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Μανιτάρια">Μανιτάρια<br>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="kreata">
        <h2 class="epik">Κρέατα</h2>
            <div class="transp">

                <input type="checkbox" value="Λαιμός">Λαιμός<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Χοιρινές">Χοιρινές<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Μοσχαρίσιες">Μοσχαρίσιες<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Παϊδάκια">Παϊδάκια<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Κοτόπουλο">Κοτόπουλο<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Μοσχάρι">Μοσχάρι<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Κατσίκι">Κατσίκι<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Κιμάς">Κιμάς<br>
            </div>  




    <div class="galaktokomika">
        <h2 class="epik">Γαλακτοκομικά</h2>
            <div class="transp">

                <input type="checkbox" value="Γάλα">Γάλα<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Γιαούρτι">Γιαούρτι<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Βούτυρο">Βούτυρο<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Ρεγκάτο">Ρεγκάτο<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Κρέμα γάλακτος">Κρέμα γάλακτος<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Τζατζίκι">Τζατζίκι<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Τυροκαφτερή">Τυροκαφτερή<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Αυγά">Αυγά<br>


            </div>  

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="thalassina">
        <h2 class="epik">Θαλασσινά</h2>
            <div class="transp">

                <input type="checkbox" value="Γαρίδες">Γαρίδες<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Μύδια">Μύδια<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Καλαμάρι">Καλαμάρι<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Θαλασσινά">Θαλασσινά<br>

                <input type="checkbox" value="Αθερίνα">Αθερίνα<br>


            </div>  

    </div>          

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing everything you need in question:

```
document.psonia.elements
```

is an `HTMLFormControlsCollection`, and like all collections, it is array-like with a `length` property.

```
document.psonia.elements.length
```

**Update**

I have no idea what you are asking.  I cut-and-pasted your form into my editor and used my `search` function to look for the number of `input` elements you have.  My editor found **35**.

```
console.log(document.psonia.elements.length);
```

also returns **35**.

Comment: Tried that as well and doesnt work this way either..(Thanks for fast response)

Comment: Then you'll have to update your question with more information -- mainly the entire form you are using.

Comment: I moved the var   numOfEl inside the    function and it works.Thank you!

Comment: Based on that, I can tell you what your issue was:  You were calculating `numOfEl` too early, before the page had finished rendering.  Such things need to be either at the bottom of the page, after everything has rendered, or inside some kind of event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i=0;i<allElements.length;i++){
  //console.log(allElements[i].id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i moved the counter of the elements inside the function and now it works.Thank you!

```
function ektipwsi() {
var numOfEl = document.psonia.elements.length;
for(var i=0; i < numOfEl ; i++){
    if(document.psonia.elements[i].checked) {
        lista.push(document.psonia.elements[i].value);
    }
};
```